# Routes and Rules Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04

Trata-se de um Servidor virtual Hyper-V Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, com cinco interfaces de rede e o squid instalado.

O que eu preciso é que quando alguém utilizar ao serviço de proxy conectando-se no IP que está na interface eth0 a saída para a internet seja através do IP que está na eth0, e assim sucessivamente para as demais interfaces.

Para tornar possível o comportamento crio novas tabelas de rota com rotas default uma para cada interface e routing policies estabelecendo se a conexão for no IP da interface correspondente deve usar a respectiva tabela de rota criada anteriormente.

**Resultado do comando ifconfig**

```
eth0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 189.189.10.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 189.189.10.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe5a:425e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 00:15:5d:5a:42:5e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 216690  bytes 15705511 (15.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 62685  bytes 4658403 (4.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 189.189.20.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 189.189.20.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe5a:425f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 00:15:5d:5a:42:5f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 154552  bytes 9944248 (9.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 32754  bytes 2319788 (2.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth2: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 189.189.30.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 189.189.30.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe5a:4260  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 00:15:5d:5a:42:60  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 154485  bytes 9940210 (9.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 32836  bytes 2330587 (2.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth3: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 189.189.40.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 189.189.40.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe5a:4261  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 00:15:5d:5a:42:61  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 117812  bytes 11016717 (11.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 34004  bytes 2504658 (2.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth4: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 189.189.50.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 189.189.50.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe5a:4262  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 00:15:5d:5a:42:62  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 118058  bytes 7940984 (7.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 35226  bytes 2705527 (2.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3101  bytes 159988 (159.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3101  bytes 159988 (159.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**Exemplo de configuração
/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth1:
      dhcp4: yes
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth2:
      dhcp4: yes
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth3:
      dhcp4: yes
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth4:
      dhcp4: yes
```

**Confiuração Das Rotas**

```
ip route add default via 189.189.10.254 dev eth0 table 10
ip route add default via 189.189.20.254 dev eth1 table 20
ip route add default via 189.189.30.254 dev eth2 table 30
ip route add default via 189.189.40.254 dev eth3 table 40
ip route add default via 189.189.50.254 dev eth4 table 50
```

**Configuração das Regras**

```
ip rule add from 189.189.10.4 table 10
ip rule add from 189.189.20.4 table 20
ip rule add from 189.189.30.4 table 30
ip rule add from 189.189.40.4 table 40
ip rule add from 189.189.50.4 table 50
```

O problema que estou enfrentando é, ao reiniciar o servidor as regras e as rotas que criei são apagadas, e ao executar um save e após o start na máquina virtual as rotas são apagadas, e apenas uma interface de rede permanence funcionando e a interface que permance funcionando é a interface cujo gateway está na primeira rota default da tabela de roteamento padrão no caso “default via 189.189.50.254 dev eth4 proto dhcp src 189.189.50.4 metric 100”, o que preciso é que as configurações de rotas e regras que fiz sejam persistentes mas das referências que consultei e executei os procedimentos não deram resultado.

**Resultado ip route show**

```
default via 189.189.50.254 dev eth4 proto dhcp src 189.189.50.4 metric 100
default via 189.189.40.254 dev eth3 proto dhcp src 167.249.40.4 metric 100
default via 189.189.30.254 dev eth2 proto dhcp src 189.189.30.254 metric 100
default via 189.189.10.254 dev eth1 proto dhcp src 189.189.10.254 metric 100
default via 189.189.20.254 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 189.189.20.254 metric 100
```

**Observações:**

1. Os IPs adicionados na pergunta são fictícios.
2. Os IPs devem ser atribuídos via DHCP.
3. Quando as rotas e regras são configuradas combinadas com a configuração do Squid o comportamento esperado é alcançado.

---------------------------**English Section (Google Translate)**-------------------------------------

Google Translate:

It is a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Hyper-V virtual server, with five network interfaces and squid installed.

What I need is that when someone uses the proxy service connecting to the IP that is in the eth0 interface the output to the internet is through the IP that is in eth0, and so on to the other interfaces.

To make possible the behavior I create new route tables with default routes one for each interface and routing policies establishing if the connection is in the IP of the corresponding interface it must use the respective route table previously created.

**ifconfig command result**

```
eth0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 189.189.10.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 189.189.10.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe5a:425e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 00:15:5d:5a:42:5e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 216690  bytes 15705511 (15.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 62685  bytes 4658403 (4.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 189.189.20.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 189.189.20.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe5a:425f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 00:15:5d:5a:42:5f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 154552  bytes 9944248 (9.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 32754  bytes 2319788 (2.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth2: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 189.189.30.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 189.189.30.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe5a:4260  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 00:15:5d:5a:42:60  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 154485  bytes 9940210 (9.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 32836  bytes 2330587 (2.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth3: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 189.189.40.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 189.189.40.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe5a:4261  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 00:15:5d:5a:42:61  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 117812  bytes 11016717 (11.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 34004  bytes 2504658 (2.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth4: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 189.189.50.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 189.189.50.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe5a:4262  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 00:15:5d:5a:42:62  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 118058  bytes 7940984 (7.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 35226  bytes 2705527 (2.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3101  bytes 159988 (159.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3101  bytes 159988 (159.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**Content on
/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth1:
      dhcp4: yes
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth2:
      dhcp4: yes
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth3:
      dhcp4: yes
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth4:
      dhcp4: yes
```

**IP Route Commands Executed**

```
ip route add default via 189.189.10.254 dev eth0 table 10
ip route add default via 189.189.20.254 dev eth1 table 20
ip route add default via 189.189.30.254 dev eth2 table 30
ip route add default via 189.189.40.254 dev eth3 table 40
ip route add default via 189.189.50.254 dev eth4 table 50
```

**IP Rule Commands Executed**

```
ip rule add from 189.189.10.4 table 10
ip rule add from 189.189.20.4 table 20
ip rule add from 189.189.30.4 table 30
ip rule add from 189.189.40.4 table 40
ip rule add from 189.189.50.4 table 50
```

Google Translate:

The problem I am facing is, when I restart the server the rules and routes I have created are deleted, and when I execute a save and after the start in the virtual machine the routes are deleted, and only one network interface is still working and the interface that permance running is the interface whose gateway is in the first default route of the default routing table in the case "default via 189.189.50.254 dev eth4 proto dhcp src 189.189.50.4 metric 100", what I need is that the route settings and rules I made are persistent but the references I consulted and performed the procedures did not work.

**Ip Route Show Commnad**

```
default via 189.189.50.254 dev eth4 proto dhcp src 189.189.50.4 metric 100
default via 189.189.40.254 dev eth3 proto dhcp src 167.249.40.4 metric 100
default via 189.189.30.254 dev eth2 proto dhcp src 189.189.30.254 metric 100
default via 189.189.10.254 dev eth1 proto dhcp src 189.189.10.254 metric 100
default via 189.189.20.254 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 189.189.20.254 metric 100
```

**Comments:**

1. The IPs added in the question are fictitious.
2. IPs must be assigned via DHCP.
3. When the routes and rules are configured in combination with the Squid configuration the expected behavior is achieved.

Comment: Added English text

Comment: @Graham if you choose to do this, then please also remove the old text or, at least, put it in a separate section.